# where is the "LSSharedFileList.h"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launch

I wanna using the API of login item, but i can not find the LaunchServices/LSSharedFileList.h, which result in the errors, such as 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "_kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems"'.

Can anyone tell me which library I should add to project? I'm using objective-c in Xcode4.2 for osx10.7.

Comment: The error message `Undefined symbols...` is a linker error not a compiler error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `ApplicationServices` framework to your project. It contains the Launch Services framework.

You add the framework to the "Link binary with libraries" section of the **Build Phases** tab of the project settings.